# Bosch fridge/freezer (B22CS / Linea 300 series) began chiming and temperature flashing on the freezer side

Tags: refrigerator, appliances, freezing

My Bosch fridge/freezer began ringing at a rapid pace randomly.

There's a display in the front, which shows a temperature to the left (freezer) and the right (fridge) directly above the built-in water dispenser on the outside of the fridge door.

The freezer temperature is flashing 0˚F and seems to not respond otherwise to temperature settings. It feels a little warm inside the fridge.

I tried resetting it by opening the right (fridge) door and pushing the power button at the top-right of the fridge door frame (power cycled over a few minutes), but the issue still persists.

I don't have the original manual and I believe this Bosch is out of warranty.

Ideas?

[image: Photo of Bosch B22CS Linea 300 series for reference (not mine)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after digging up the [appropriate manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7xGp.jpg) for the Bosch B22CS30SNS)][2](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/217807/Bosch-B22cs30sns.html?page=13#manual) online. Something was preventing the freezer from cooling, which triggered the temperature warning.

> The temperature warning signal switches on if the freezer or the refrigerator compartment is too warm and the food is at risk of thawing.

Here are the steps I took to resolve the issue:

- Exited alert mode: to do this, all I had to do was hold the `alarm/lock` button for two seconds or so—this showed me that the actual temperature inside the fridge and stopped the blinking
- Reset: turned off the unit by pushing the power button on the top right of the door frame (opened the fridge and it's in the corner, near the hinge), waited a minute, and powered back on
- Pulled out the large ice tray (just in case) and emptied out most of the ice (there was a lot)—when I put it back, I made sure it was fully inserted and flush
- Got rid of any items that might have been blocking the freezer door—I didn't see anything obvious, but my freezer was pretty full, and I think this may have been the culprit
- Closed the freezer fully, making sure the door wasn't even slightly being pushed open by an item inside
- Just in case, I set it into "Super" mode which rapidly cools down the freezer or fridge over 6 hours
- To do this, I pressed `freezer` and then `super`, which activated a quiet but audible change in the cooling system

Fortunately my food had not thawed yet and now it's on its way to being frozen again.

### ⚠ Careful with these fridges, because it isn't clear when the door is not fully closed

([[image: Photo of front of unit in super mode (after fix)]

[image: Page 13 of Bosch B22CS30SNS Manual]